# Excel cell has NA and only refreshed when you focus into the cell and hit Enter

Tags: excel

I have a very strange Excel issue and wondering if anyone has experienced such problem before.

I received a file from a colleague that some of the cells are showing #N/A values when the file is opened.  If I focus into the cell, then the formula text box at the top and press Enter key then the cell is re-calculated with the proper value.

The cell formula is a simple VLOOKUP function:

```
=VLOOKUP(A174, OTHERSHEET!$B$4:$G$580, 6, FALSE)
```

Couple other observations:

1. If I click on the yellow exclamation button and Evaluate the formula then it still resolves to #N/A
2. The workbook calculation settings is already set to Automatic.
3. Pressing F9 or Recalculate Now/Sheet from the Formulas ribbon does not fix it.

The file was created from Excel 2013 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

The file may have a bad dependency tree.  Try using:

**Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F9**